# UE4 iTween C++ throws "this was nullptr"

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, itween

I'm trying to use iTween (via C++, not BP) to rotate an actor to face another, but it throwing an exception in `Actor.h` that says:

[image]

I'm using the following code to start the tween:

```
AActor* actorToRotate = Cast<AActor>(this);

if (actorToRotate != nullptr && CharacterToAttack != nullptr)
{

    FRotator rotationFrom = actorToRotate->GetActorRotation();
    FRotator rotationTo = CharacterToAttack->GetActorRotation();
    FName tweenName = TEXT("turret");

    AiTweenEvent* TurretTween = UiTween::ActorRotateFromToSimple(tweenName, actorToRotate, rotationFrom, rotationTo, CoordinateSpace::world, false, 2.0f, easeInAndOutQuartic);

}
```

Rather than using the `actorToRotate` variable I've tried using `this` in `ActorRotateFromToSimple()` but I get the same error.

```
if (CharacterToAttack != nullptr)
{

    FRotator rotationFrom = GetActorRotation();
    FRotator rotationTo = CharacterToAttack->GetActorRotation();
    FName tweenName = TEXT("turret");

    AiTweenEvent* TurretTween = UiTween::ActorRotateFromToSimple(tweenName, this, rotationFrom, rotationTo, CoordinateSpace::world, false, 2.0f, easeInAndOutQuartic);

}
```

If anyone smarter than me shed some light onto this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Additional information I think might be important:

1. `actorToRotate` is custom type of `ATDWeapon` that extends from `AActor`
2. `CharacterToAttack` is custom type of `ATDAICharacter` that extends from `ATDCharacter`
3. The function that executes this code is called by `GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer()`
4. I've added `#include "iTween/iTween.h"` to the top of my `TDWeapon.cpp` file

Comment: Learn [how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and backtrace the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the problem wasn't in the code. I was using "simulate in editor" in the UE4 Editor rather than "play in editor".

It appears that `AiTweenEvent* UiTween::SpawnEvent(AiTAux* aux)` needs a player controller and uses `GetWorldLocal()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPawn()->GetTransform()` to get it's transform. In my instance, "simulate in editor" doesn't spawn a player so `GetPawn()` returns `nullptr` which `GetTransform()` doesn't like.

Awesome.